# Sails JS - favicon not showing

Tags: javascript, html, sails.js, favicon

I have created a Sails JS app. I have added favicon icon by adding following line in layout.js

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="wb-favicon.png"/>
```

This works for the routes like "/dashboard","/user" but not working for routes like "/reports/myreport","/user/add". In short if I use multilevel routes the favicon not showing.

Any solution?

Comment: You need to add an absolute or relative path to the file.  For example in reports/myreport page change it to href="../wb-favicon.png" and I'm guessing it will work assuming the png is located up one directory.

Comment: Use  href="/wb-favicon.png" it will wark for all. '../' goes one level up only. '/' goes to the top.

Answer (score 0):

Changing things in layout will never work because the layout is built dynamically.What you can do is:

Rename your file `wb-favicon.png` to `favicon.ico` and remove the browsers cache and see your thing will work.Make sure you keep `favicon.ico` in `assets` directory.